# UIBarButtonItem appearance not working on the device

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I ran into the following problem:

I'm customizing the whole appearance of my app. Now I want to change the background of the backbuttons in the navigationbar. If I run my code on the simulator, it works. But if I run it on the device it doesn't change anything. How is this possible?

I'm running the app on my iPhone 4S iOS 5.0.1

```
#import "test.h"
#import "InfoButton.h"

@implementation test

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    if([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
        //iOS 5 new UINavigationBar custom background
        UIImage *navi = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navi forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
        UIImage *toolbarBackButtonBackgroundPortrait = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_back.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 17, 0, 6)];

        [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:toolbarBackButtonBackgroundPortrait forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    } 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton * infoDarkButtonType = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight] retain];
    infoDarkButtonType.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 25.0);
    infoDarkButtonType.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [infoDarkButtonType addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoDarkButtonType];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = infoButton;
    [infoDarkButtonType release];
    [infoButton release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the spelling of the image file, especially caps.  I've noticed that the simulator will ignore caps and still load the file while the device is case sensitive.  I've done that a few times myself.

Comment: Thank you very much, i saved it under nav_bar.PNG, now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. My image was named "add.png" and used [UIImage imageNamed:@"add.png"] in code. While this was working in simulator, it was not on device.

I renamed the file to "Add.png" (capital A) and changed in code to [UIImage imageNamed:@"Add.png"]. This fixed the issue and not works both in simulator and device - weird :/